# Tomcat myfaces dynamic source files

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, facelets

I'm going to try and make as much sense as possible here. We are working on a myfaces 2 app in tomcat. On our local dev machines, whenever we want to change one of our xhtml files, we have to stop the server, deploy and then start the server back up. 
This is cumbersome and makes making small changes to the view tedious.
I tried changing the deployed xhtml file in tomcat, but the server only picks up the  new change after a restart.

Is there any type of config in myfaces or tomcat I can do to force the rebuilding of these source xhtml's every time?

Comment: Are you doing the changes in the xhtml files via IDE (eclipse), or manually directly in webapps?

Comment: doing the changes directly in the IDE and then copied to the webapps directory. We are not running the Tomcat from the eclips IDE.

Comment: For starters you can reload the application only and not restart the server by doing: `http://path:port/manager/reload?path=/APP_PATH`. Which Tomcat are you using?Did you modify the configuration?

Comment: @user384706 : We are using Tomcat 6.0.20, as far as I know the only config change we made was to run it on port 8090 and the AJP for apache httpd on port 8019. We had been able to replace files on the go in the past with other projects, so I know it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, after some more intensive googling, slaughtering and then burning the sacrficial lamb, doing the sacred developers dance and drinking the magic (java) potion I found the answer. If you want to know the answer, pay $500 into my paypal account....

....

ok seriously. You just need to add the following to your web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It was that simple!

Comment: Strange.I tried in a trivial JSF project in Tomcat 6.0.29 without these entries in the web.xml and the modified xhtml files were update immediately.The only similar context param I have in web.xml is javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE set to Development.None of the others

Comment: I found that context param here http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/webconfig.html, but it has no description. I'll give it a bash and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should start tomcat server in debug mode. If you are using an IDE such as eclipse , it is straight forward.

Comment: what about  classes you have modified?. can tomcat load new version of the modified classes?.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem with you, and i'm using eclipse and Tomcat Server, and then i try to change the tomcat configuration in Publishing option set to Automatically publish when resource change.

It works for me..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Answers should help the question-asker solve their problem -- telling them that it worked for you is not the best way to do that.  This would probably be better as a comment.